# Reclassifying raster using numpy

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, numpy, reclassify

I have more than 300 NDVI, Soil Salinity and NDMI Calculated Rasters I want to reclassify into categories based on percentages of values like this function:

```
def classify_salinity(ras):
    max_val = np.nanmax(ras)
    min_val = np.nanmin(ras)
    #scaling between 0-100%
    scaled = ((ras - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)) * 100
    """
    reclassifying according to critera
    Criteria for Salinity:
    {>80% == 1, 50-80% == 2, 20-50% == 3, <20% == 4}
    """
    # Float to integer and copy array
    arr = scaled
    arr[(arr < 20)] = 4
    arr[(arr >= 80)] = 1
    arr[(arr >= 50) & (arr < 80)] = 2
    arr[(arr >= 20) & (arr < 50)] = 3
    # arr[(arr < 0)] = 0

    return scaled
```

The issue is that this function executes statements line by line on the array which can introduce complications.

Is there a way to do this all in one statement using numpy?

Comment: What do you mean by "one statement"? One line of code?

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910271/reclassify-raster-values-using-python-numpy).

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate all over array, if that helps?

```
def reclassify(arr, rows, cols):
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            temp_value = arr[r][c]
            if temp_value < 20:
               temp_value = 4

            elif temp_value >=80:
               temp_value = 1
    
            elif (temp_value >=50) and (temp_value <80):
               temp_value = 2
    
            elif (temp_value >=20) and (temp_value <50):
               temp_value = 3
    
            else:
               pass
            
            arr[r][c] = temp_value
    
    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in my test

```
    import numpy as np
    from osgeo import gdal
    
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    file = gdal.Open('example.tif')
    band = file.GetRasterBand(1)
    ras = band.ReadAsArray()
    max_val = np.nanmax(ras)
    min_val = np.nanmin(ras)
    
    #scaling between 0-100%
    lista = ((ras - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)) * 100
    
    # reclassification
    list_dest = lista.copy()
    
    list_dest[np.where(lista >= 80)] = 1
    list_dest[np.where((lista >= 50) & (lista < 80)) ] = 2
    list_dest[np.where((lista >= 20) & (lista < 50)) ] = 3
    list_dest[np.where(lista < 20)] = 4
    # create new file
    file2 = driver.Create( 'example_reclassed.tif', file.RasterXSize , file.RasterYSize , 1)
    file2.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(list_dest)
    
    # spatial ref system
    proj = file.GetProjection()
    georef = file.GetGeoTransform()
    file2.SetProjection(proj)
    file2.SetGeoTransform(georef)
    file2.FlushCache()
```